# What if the user is still authenticated and the access token expires?

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, openid-connect, end-user

I am currently studying Oauth 2.0 and OIDC, and I have a confusion about access tokens. If the end-user is still interacting with the application and the access token the app obtained from the Authorization Server expires , what should the application do if it has no refresh token and needs to access some resources ? Should the end-user be reauthenticated ?

Thank you in advance for you help

Comment: Usually you have a refresh token. If you don't, you indeed need to initiate auth from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If the access token is expired and you have no refresh token, then you have to let the user sign-in and reauthenticate. Sometimes the OIDC server can remember the user and auto-signin the user again. But how this is done is very implementation specific. How this is done is outside the scope of the [specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).